# Showing a quotient ring is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Question:
>
> Let R be the ring of all continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ under point-wise addition and multiplication.
>
> Show that $ I=\left \{ f \in R \mid \left ( 0 \right )f=0\right \}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

Now, by first isomorphism theorem for rings,

$R/Ker\left ( \phi \right )\cong \left ( R \right )\phi$

> Observe that $Ker\left ( \phi \right )=I \ and \ \left ( R \right )\phi=\mathbb{R}$

Recall that for a commutative ring R with unity,

> R/I is a field If and only If I is a maximal idea of R.

It suffice to show R/I is a field and recall that a field is an integral domain in which every non-zero elements is a unit.

Here is where I am confused:
Clearly, the elements in R/I are $a+I :\forall a \in R$.
Right off the bat, the elements a are functions in R and functions are in general not commutative.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The functions form a ring under pointwise multiplication, so clearly the ring is commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking of the fact that composition of functions is not commutative. But in this case, the operation is pointwise multiplication, not composition: pointwise multiplication is commutative.

Comment: This confirms my confusion. Thanks.